# Bugged DCG in SWI-Prolog?

Tags: prolog, dcg

after reading about DCGs in Prolog I've decided to make my own, but I've ran into some problems with running it in debug/trace and in normal mode. Here's code:

```
% unworthy_content(?Chars, ?Rest).
% VAR: Chars - read chars
% VAR: Rest - helps with fast concat of lists.
% FUNC: will read chars until it finds <%
unworthy_content(Y, Y), [60, 37] -->
  [60, 37].
unworthy_content([H|R], Y) -->
  [H],
  unworthy_content(R, Y).

% worthy_content(?Chars, ?Rest).
% VAR: Chars - chars inside <% %>
% VAR: Rest - see unworthy content.
% FUNC: will get chars between <% and %>.
worthy_content(Y, Y) -->
  [37, 62].
worthy_content([H|R], Y) -->
  [H],
  worthy_content(R, Y).

% Page(?Content).
% FUNC: will read file and gets content of page, removing <% %>
page([]) -->
  [-1].
page(X) -->
  [60, 37],
  worthy_content(X, Y),
  page(Y).
page(X) -->
  unworthy_content(X, Y),
  page(Y).
```

I also had this simple file:

```
<html>
<head>
<%say_hi(X), blabla(X)%>
<%say_hello(X)%>
<%world%>
</head>
</html>
```

The problem is, when I run this command in debug/trace mode:

```
phrase_from_file(page(X), 'file').
```

everything just works. But when I try to run that same command in normal mode, I get error: Out of local stack. Does anyone knows how that is possible?

I run Windows 10, SWI-Prolog version 7.4.1.

Comment: Actually, you would have the same problem in trace mode if you were able to press the creep button an infinite number of times. :) So I don't think it "just works" in that case. I tried it in trace mode and it never terminated. It just kept outputing new trace lines on each "creep". Check your trace output and look carefully for repeating or growing patterns indicate that the code is not narrowing down on termination.

Comment: This clause looks suspicious: `unworthy_content(Y, Y), [60, 37] -->
  [60, 37].` which, in conjunction with `page(X) -->
  unworthy_content(X, Y),
  page(Y).` could lead to an infinite recursion.

Comment: Are these ASCII codes?

Comment: @false Yeah, they're ASCII codes.

Comment: @lurker You were probably right, I tried to simplify my DCG so it would correspond to simple finite automaton for this problem and now it works as intended.

Comment: `[60, 37]` can be written as `[ 0'<, 0'%]` ; and as "<%" with `set_prolog_flag(double_quotes, codes)`. Even better redable, you could use `set_prolog_flag(double_quotes, chars)` to use [a,b] as "ab".